# Cannot copy/cut and paste from file manager to Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, copy, paste, copy-and-paste

[VIDEO](https://i.imgur.com/4d7SJdz.mp4)

I cannot copy and paste files from the file manager to Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The file manager window you have open has a "Desktop" entry in the left navigation bar. Drop your file there and it will appear on the desktop.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you are not running a Mac or Windows.

What you can do in the file manager, is copy the file and then navigate to the folder //home//Desktop and paste it there.